# MSIL x86 mismatch when PCL project

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, windows-10, portable-class-library

Since a couple of days I have a very strange error when building PCL project with profile 259. It gives me the following erro:

> There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project
>   being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference
>   "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll", "x86"

This is only happening when building for PCL profile259. If I change it to profile 78 for example everything works. 
I am also missing the .NET reference in the references list (for profile259)

I already reinstalled Visual Studio 2015 and 2017, but nothing seems to work.And I also ran the NetFXRepairTool, and tried to reinstall the different .NET frameworks. (I am running W10).

Is there anyone who might have the solution to solve this?

Comment: The warning is normal when you have a reference to that copy of mscorlib.dll.  But you must never have a reference to it, it needs to come from the C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\ .NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile259\mscorlib.dll.  Using the copy in the c:\windows subdirectory can certainly cause problems, it isn't really PCL anymore.  Without at least a detailed build trace it is impossible to guess how this could have happened.

Comment: How do I change the reference to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\ .NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile259\mscorlib.dll` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it seems I've solved the issue.
My Profile259 folder didn't contain any dll files. For now I copied the dll from profile 78 folder, which seems to work for now. I will replace them by a copy of profile 259 though.